# Does Azure RemoteApp failover

Tags: azure

I am looking at an Azure RemoteApp deployment (as opposed to a straight VM/RDS Solution) I've read through the documentation though and I can't figure out what it does if a region fails.

If I deploy RemoteApp in West Europe (for instance) if that region is taken offline what would it take to bring it back up in North Europe with the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, RemoteApp is tied to a specific region and won't automatically fail over.

However, if this is a concern there is nothing to stop you replicating your RemoteApp image to a second region ready to be used in the event of a disaster. The only cost for this would be the storage, which would be small, and you only create the RemoteApp instance and add users to it when needed. If you needed automated fail over you would need to look at some sort of scripting/Azure automation to do this for you.